# Objective-C – Waiting for two async methods to complete

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa, asynchronous, wait

I'm calling four methods that I want to execute in synchronous order, the first two methods are synchronous, the last two methods are asynchronous (data fetching from URLs).

Pseudo-code:

```
- (void)syncData {

    // Show activity indicator
    [object sync]; // Synchronous method
    [object2 sync]; // Synchronous method
    BOOL object3Synced = [object3 sync]; // Async method
    BOOL object4Synced = [object4 sync]; // Async method
    // Wait for object3 and object4 has finished and then hide activity indicator
}
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Pseudo code is not good here. To help we have to know what kind of asynchronous mechanism you use.

Comment: @PeterWarbo If `object3` and `object4` have some interface to notify you when their operations complete, you need to edit your post and show us that interface.

Comment: `object3` is downloading a file through `NSURLRequest` and `object4` is using the Facebook SDK to download data (which I believe behind the scenes is also using `NSURLRequest`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you actually have some sort of way of knowing when the asynchronous methods are done, what you probably want is something like:

```
- (void)syncData {

    // Show activity indicator
    [object sync]; // Synchronous method
    [object2 sync]; // Synchronous method

    _object3Synced = _object4Synced = NO;
    [object3 syncWithCompletionHandler:
          ^{
               _object3Synced = YES;
               [self considerHidingActivityIndicator];
          }]; // Async method
    [object4 syncWithCompletionHandler:
          ^{
               _object4Synced = YES;
               [self considerHidingActivityIndicator];
          }]; // Async method
}

- (void)considerHidingActivityIndicator
{
     if(_object3Synced && _object4Synced)
     {
         // hide activity indicator, etc
     }
}
```

Comment: That was about the same way I had imagined that I would implement it as well with a block completion handler... thanks for your input

Comment: +1 - of course object4 method can't depend on processing of the object3 method call ...

Answer (score 25):

Use a barrier:

`void dispatch_barrier_async(dispatch_queue_t queue, dispatch_block_t block);`

> Submits a barrier block for asynchronous execution and returns immediately.
>
> When the barrier block reaches the front of a private concurrent
>   queue, it is not executed immediately. 
>   Instead, **the queue waits until its currently executing blocks finish executing**. 
>   At that point, the
>   queue executes the barrier block by itself. Any blocks submitted after
>   the barrier block are not executed until the barrier block completes.

This example outputs `1 2 3 4 done` although being asynchronous, it could be `1 2 4 3 done`. Since I understand you want to handle an activity indicator, this shouldn't matter.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_queue_create("com.myqueue", 0);
        dispatch_sync(queue,  ^(){NSLog(@"1");} );
        dispatch_sync(queue,  ^(){NSLog(@"2");});
        dispatch_async(queue, ^(){NSLog(@"3");});
        dispatch_async(queue, ^(){NSLog(@"4");});
        dispatch_barrier_sync(queue, ^(){NSLog(@"done");});
    }
}
```

For other ways to test asynchronous code, see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11179523/412916

Comment: If you don't mind concurrent execution of the async methods, use `DISPATCH_QUEUE_CONCURRENT` (available in iOS 5) instead 0 when creating the queue.

Comment: This assumes that both of the asynchronous operations are on the same queue, and that that queue is reachable from the code that would schedule the barrier.

Answer (score 3):

You can make a subclass of `UIActivityInidicator`, add an `activityCount` property and implement these two additional methods:

```
- (void)incrementActivityCount
{
    if(_activityCount == 0)
    {
        [self startAnimating];
    }
    _activityCount++;
}

- (void)decrementActivityCount
{
    _activityCount--;
    if(_activityCount <= 0)
    {
        _activityCount = 0;
        [self stopAnimating];
    }
}
```

Now whenever you start something that uses the activity counter call `incrementActivityCount` and in its completion block (or otherwise when it finishes) call `decrementActivityCount`. You can do other things if you want in these methods, the above is just a simple example which is probably sufficient in most cases (especially if you set `hidesWhenStopped = YES`).

Comment: @Daij-Djan These should be called on the main thread of course as should anything that touches the UI. Whenever you are dealing with completion blocks to update the UI you should ensure they are dispatched to the main queue.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to launch the first Async method and use a completion block.  In the completion block of the first async method, you would launch your second async method.  Though this kind of makes using async methods irrelevant.

Comment: Yes, you lose the benefit of making the two async calls parallel but you don't lose all of the benefits - at least it's off the UI thread and doesn't hang.  If second async method depended on processing of the first, then this is the way to go.  Otherwise the other answers are better.

Comment: Yep, BTW I didn't down vote - the OPs question was ambiguous with pseudo code.  Also if they are dependent on each other, your answer is better.