# Objective-C – Two async methods, waiting for condition

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa, asynchronous, wait

I'm running two async methods (see this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13653130/294661) for reference).

It's working perfect except when I have this scenario. When an error occurs in either of the methods I will display this information for the user so in the block I will check for error and do this:

```
if(error) {
    int64_t delayInSeconds = 2.0;
    dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC);
    dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), {

    // Show a popup for 2.0 seconds alerting the user of the error
    });
}
```

This works without issue. But the issue occurs when **both** these async operations have errors. The first method that finishes will show the error for maybe just 0.5 seconds, and then the second async operation will show it's error for 2.0 seconds (not taking in consideration that there is already an error message being showed).

So I need some process to check if there is already an error message being showed, then wait for that error message to go away (2.0 seconds) and then immediately show the second error message.

Comment: If the two methods both have reference to a common object, you can set a flag in that object and have each method check for the flag before it shows its own error message.

Comment: @Jonathan, sharing objects between threads is a recipe for disaster.

Comment: Fair point, better use notifications instead.  Have each method post begin/end alert notifications that the other method listens for, so it knows if an alert is already on-screen.

Comment: @PeterWarbo How are you showing the error to the user?  `UIAlertView`?  Something else?  Does it have a way to call a completion block or send a message to a delegate when it goes away?

Comment: @robmayoff I'm using SSHUDView (it doesn't have completion blocks or delegates by default unfortunately)

Comment: How does the HUD view get dismissed?

Comment: You call dismiss on the HUD when you want it to go away.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you just need to implement a queue for displaying these errors to the user.  You could do it as a category on `SSHUDView`, with a simple interface like this:

```
@interface SSHUDView (queue)
- (void)showForDuration:(NSTimeInterval)duration;
@end
```

Implement it by using a serial GCD queue:

```
@implementation SSHUDView (queue)

- (void)showForDuration:(NSTimeInterval)duration {
    static dispatch_once_t once;
    static dispatch_queue_t queue;
    dispatch_once(&once, ^{
         queue = dispatch_queue_create("SSHUDView(serial)", 0);
    });

    dispatch_async(queue, ^{
        dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [self show];
        });

        usleep(duration * USEC_PER_SEC);

        dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [self dismiss];
        });
    });
}

@end
```

Comment: Thanks Rob I will try this out in a little while!

Comment: Thanks that worked like a charm. One question though, is it necessary to put the actions inside dispatch_async when it will run synchronously?

Comment: Right, and what is the reason you are using dispatch_sync inside dispatch_async?

Comment: Suppose you used `dispatch_async` to run `[self show]` and `[self dismiss]`.  And suppose the main queue were running some long blocking operation that took 3 seconds to complete.  (You shouldn't do long blocking operations on the main queue, but what if…) Then `[self show]` and `[self dismiss]` would both end up waiting in the main queue for the long operation to complete, and then would run one after another with no delay between them.

Comment: So dispatch_sync will wait until main queue is empty and then perform the actions? Otherwise they would be put on the queue immediately and the usleep would be made in the background thread while the `[self show]` and `[self dismiss]` were waiting on the main queue?

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to Rob Mayoff's good answer, you might want to instead refactor you UI.  Having dialogs pop up one after the other can be a bit tedious for both you and the end user.  In fact having dialogs pop up at all can be tedious, especially if they're modal (even just as sheets).

Perhaps you could do something a little more interesting?  Like have the errors display as a banner that slides down from the top of your window.  If you have multiple errors you just have multiple banners, one below the other.  They'd then fade out in appropriate time (though be careful with auto-dismissal, as the user may not be watching your app consistently).

Another approach is to have one dialog, but change or append to its message when additional errors occur.  This has the downside that the dialog may change while the user is reading it, so you have to be both careful and think carefully about whether that's appropriate.  It's mostly useful in situations where the errors are closely related, e.g. you try to connect to your server, but it fails.  So you show an error message at the same time as you start a general network connectivity test.  When that test comes back and says that the network is gone completely, you update your dialog to clarify that it's not the server that's down but rather your internet connection.

Alternatively, if you're displaying these more as overlays in the same vein as volume change indicators, you might just want to display them side-by-side.  You could even be fancy and have the existing one(s) slide to the left to make room for the new one, though unless they're very simple icons, that might make it hard for the user to follow what's going on.