# Objective-C – Queuing up and delaying UIKit messages

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, grand-central-dispatch

I'm delaying `UIKit` messages as per this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13662842/294661)

Now another requirement has arisen, instead of just queuing `SSHUDView` method calls we should also handle queing of `UIAlertView`. For example one scenario could be that we display a hud then after 1 second we display another hud and then finally after 1 second we display a `UIAlertView`.

The problem is now that since the `SSHUDView`s are run asynchronously on a background thread when I get to display the `UIAlertView` the `SSHUDView`s have not finished displaying so the `UIAlertView` will overlay the hud.

Basically I need a way to queue up and delay methods whether they are of class `SSHUDView` or `UIAlertView`. A feedback queue, where you can delay individual messages.

Comment: I would build a basic notification queueing system. You can post SSHUDViews and UIAlertViews to it and it will display them one after the other.

Answer (score 1):

What you're talking about sounds like a perfect fit for [semaphores](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/OperationQueues/OperationQueues.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091-CH102-SW24) (see under the heading *Using Dispatch Semaphores to Regulate the Use of Finite Resources*)! I saw the SO Answer you linked to and I don't think it solves the case of `UIView` animations. Here's how I'd use semaphores.

In your view controller add an instance variable `dispatch_semaphore_t _animationSemaphore;` and initialize it in the `- init` method:

```
- (id)init
{
  if ((self = [super init])) {
    _animationSemaphore = dispatch_semaphore_create(1);
  }
  return self;
}
```

(Don't forget to release the semaphore in the `- dealloc` method using `dispatch_release`. You also might want to wait for queued animations to finish by using `dispatch_semaphore_wait`, but I'll leave that for you to figure out.)

When you want to queue up an animation, you'll do something like this:

```
- (void)animateSomething
{
  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_LOW, 0), ^{
    dispatch_semaphore_wait(_animationSemaphore, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
      [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
        // Your fancy animation code
      } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        dispatch_semaphore_signal(_animationSemaphore);
      }];
    });
  });
}
```

You can use the `- animateSomething` template to accomplish different things, such as displaying an `SSHUDView` or a `UIAlertView`.

Answer (score 0):

What you're describing sounds like an animation. Why not just use UIView animation and chain the series of animation blocks:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:2
     animations:^{
         // display first HUD
     }
     completion:^(BOOL finished){
         [UIView animateWithDuration:2
              animations:^{
                  // hide first HUD, display second HUD
              }
              completion:^(BOOL finished){
                  [UIView animateWithDuration:2
                       animations:^{
                           // hide second HUD, show UIAlert
                       }
                       completion:nil
                   ];
              }
          ];
     }
 ];
```