# Wait for flag from background thread

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, cocoa

Upon starting my program I fire a second thread to do some background work. This thread will never die but I need to wait for it to finish what it's doing before allowing the main thread to continue.

How can I block and resume the main thread while I wait for the second thread to update it's status?

Comment: Have you tried anything, or do you know how to do it in another language?

Comment: I had a while() with usleep() in it, but it's sub-optimal. There must be an API call I can use to wake up the parent thread as soon as I need it.

Comment: Runloop, semaphore, or group. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/818674/412916

Comment: Why are you bothering with a background thread if you want to block the main thread anyway? The point of using a background thread is to ensure the main thread doesn't get locked

Comment: @CStreel, I can see a lot of reasons. He might launch the thread then do something else then have to wait.

Comment: "This thread will never die but I need to wait for it to finish what it's doing before allowing the main thread to continue." - so it will finish, but not stop? Can you provide an example of when you would want the thread to finish, but run forever?

Comment: @CStreel The main thread should never be blocked.

Comment: @xagyg Cocoaster's question is a standard pattern; background service thread (which ought to be a queue, but.. OK) has some required stuff to do to set up and then sits around and takes work requests.   Very common model prior to queue based designs.

Comment: @bbum I know it shouldn't but he clearly states that he wants to. @ zneak That is what things like callbacks and semaphores are for, with what we have available for us I doubt there will ever be a time to where it becomes required to block the main thread to achieve the desired result

Comment: I open an SSH tunnel before opening a database connection. Without the tunnel the connection won't work. I need to wait for it to finish connecting and then keep it around until the connection closes.

Comment: @CStreel Doesn't matter if he wants to block the main thread or not; it shouldn't be blocked and it doesn't need to be blocked.  Desire motivated by ignorance does not make the desired behavior correct. ;)

Comment: @bbum I am well aware of that and was not encouraging the behaviour. I was merely trying to determine his logic for coming to that solution

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, don't block the main thread.  Not ever.  Blocking the main thread long enough on iOS will cause your app to be killed.  On OS X, it'll cause the rainbow pizza of death to show up.

Ultimately, blocking the main thread causes your app to be unresponsive.

Instead, have the application throw up a modal dialog or modal sheet or some other status indicator that indicates that the app is doing something that must be done before progress continues.   Make sure the "quit" menu item is still enabled in case the user decides "oh, crap! no time for this! abort! abort! abort!".

Then, when your background thread is done, use any of the various mechanisms to dispatch to the main thread (GCD, performSelector:..., etc...) that then makes the "initializing" modality go away.

No need to poll, sleep, or while(){} at all.

---

> My background thread isn't done, it lives more or less forever. And I
>   need it to reach a certain state before the main thread can do it's
>   thing.

Exactly;  so, when it reaches that state, you could use:

```
 [someObject performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(sshConnectionEstablished:) withObject:nil];
```

Where `someObject` might likely be your application delegate.

Or you could use notifications and do something like:

```
 dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationNamed:@"MySSHConnectionEstablished" ....];
 });
```

Note that whether you want it to be async or sync is up to you.

Comment: My background thread isn't done, it lives more or less forever. And I need it to reach a certain state before the main thread can do it's thing.

Comment: Why would one want to dispatch_async `postNotificationNamed` ? Shouldn't it return immediately anyway. FWIW, if you google "dispatch_async postNotificationNamed" this is the only result that comes up!

Comment: @Mojo66 `postNotificationNamed:` is synchronous, not asynchronous.  It also posts the notification on the thread it was called on.  So, if you need to update UI, you would want the notification posted on the main thread and you would generally do that using `dispatch_async()` or you'll risk deadlock.

Comment: Ok, UI updates need to happen on the main queue. But that doesn't mean you should post a notification on the main queue only because it is supposed to change the UI. A notification handler should never make assumptions about the thread it is called on. Instead post the notification synchronously on a background queue and handle the notification asynchronously on the main queue. This also avoids an object sent with the notification to get autoreleased immediately because in your code snippet `dispatch_async` returns immediately and the notification handler could receive a `nil` object.